# Increment the name of variable

Tags: javascript, loops, variables, increment

Basically I want to increment the name of the variable. What is the correct syntax to do this?

```
for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
    eval("var slider_" + i);

    var slider_+i = function(){
    //some code
}

dojo.addOnLoad(slider_+i);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not just use an array?

```
var slider = [];

for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
    slider[i] = function(){
        //some code
    }

    dojo.addOnLoad(slider[i]);
}
```

---

Alternatively, you could access them based on the object they are contained within.  Assuming they are global variables (hopefully not):

```
for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
    window["slider_"+i] = function(){
        //some code
    }

    dojo.addOnLoad(window["slider_"+i]);
}
```

`window["something"]` is another way to access a global variable named `something`.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do so is to use an object or array. This should work:

```
var slider = {}; // object
// var slider = [] ; // array
for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
    slider[i] = function() {
        // some code ...
    }
    dojo.addOnLoad(slider[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To increment a variable name, you can transform a key-value array into an object.

```js
  const variablesArray = []

  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    variablesArray.push([`key${i}`, `value${i}`])
  }

  let result = Object.fromEntries(variablesArray)

  console.log(result.key0) // return value0
  console.log(result.key1) // return value1
  console.log(result.key2) // return value2
  console.log(result.key3) // return value3
  console.log(result.key4) // return value4
```

We use Object.fromEntries to return an object created by key-value entries for properties and methods