# How to console.log Incremental variable Such as a1,a2,a3,a4 with Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm learng some code with Javascript.
I would like to console.log Increment Variable such as `a1,a2,a3,a4` and so on.
How can I implement it?

My only solution is `eval()` in a for loop:

`console.log(eval('a'+i)).`

However, it's not recommended in javascript.

```
var a1=10,a2=15,a3=20;
for(var i=1;i<=3;i++){
  console.log(eval('a'+i));
}
```

Comment: if this is in the global scope ... `console.log(this['a'+i])`

Comment: If those were globals you can do `window['a'+i]`. That's just a curiosity, you should not make them globals.

Comment: Store the values in an array? Then you can do `a[1], a[2], a[i]...`

Comment: @Herohtar is correct - what you're looking for is an array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Increment the name of variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7730761/increment-the-name-of-variable) and [How do I create dynamic variable names inside a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8260156)

Comment: BoBo, Welcome to JavaScript. If you have a requirement like this then you should create an array of objects like var a =  [{a: 10},{a: 15},{a: 30}]; a.map((item) => console.log(item.a)). This is also a use case may vary on requirements.

Comment: @BoBo Please do not edit your question for an unrelated one, specially after receiving answers. I rolled your edit back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you create an array to store all your `a` elements like so:

```
var arr = [10, 15, 20];
```

Which you can then loop over using a for loop. In the array the 0<sup>th</sup> index represents the `a1` and the n-1<sup>th</sup> index represents `an`:

```js
var arr = [10, 15, 20];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  console.log(arr[i]);
}
```

Another approach would be to use an object, where `a1`, `a2`, ... `an` are keys in your object:

```
var obj = {
  'a1': 10,
  'a2': 15,
  'a3': 20
}
```

You can then use bracket notation to access your keys and values:

```js
var obj = {
  'a1': 10,
  'a2': 15,
  'a3': 20
}

for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
  console.log(obj['a' + i]);
}
```

...or use a `for...in` loop to loop over your properties instead:

```js
var obj = {
  'a1': 10,
  'a2': 15,
  'a3': 20
}

for (var prop in obj) {
  console.log(obj[prop]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks,Sir.  It works well. That helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = [10, 15, 20];
for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++){
    console.log("The value of a[i] is", a[i]);
}
```

Comment: If you're working with modern JavaScript, you could look into a `for of` loop, declaring the variable reference `a` as `const` etc

Comment: Thanks ,Sir.However,the key is i don't know the value of variable stored in Array.